# SagePay not sending notification emails when using the Form Integration method

Tags: opayo

I am using the SagePayMVC (https://github.com/JeremySkinner/SagePayMvc) component in an ASP.Net/C# application to process payments on a website using SagePay.

Everything is working fine except that SagePay does not send notification emails to the vendor or customer on successful completion of an order.

I contacted SagePay support regarding this issue. they say that I am not passing the VendorEMail parameter to SagePay. But I am passing all the required parameters to SagePay.

The post request(captured using Fiddler on my development machine) that is made to SagePay

---

POST https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: test.sagepay.com
Content-Length: 781
Expect: 100-continue

VPSProtocol=2.23&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=***&VendorTxCode=20&Amount=17.05&Currency=GBP&Description=Shopping+Basket+for&NotificationURL=http://****&BillingSurname=**&BillingFirstnames=**&BillingAddress1=b+add11&BillingAddress2=b+add2&BillingCity=b+city&BillingPostCode=WR2+6N&BillingCountry=GB&BillingPhone=1234&DeliverySurname=ghj&DeliveryFirstnames=ghj&DeliveryAddress1=d+add1&DeliveryAddress2=d+add2&DeliveryCity=d+city&DeliveryPostCode=WR2+6N&DeliveryCountry=GB&DeliveryPhone=1234&CustomerEMail=****&VendorEMail=emailaddress%40example.com&Basket=2%3a***++2%3a1%3a5.25%3a0.00%3a5.25%3a5.25%3aPostage%3a1%3a1.80%3a0.00%3a1.80%3a1.80&AllowGiftAid=0&Apply3DSecure=0&Profile=NORMAL

---

I have no idea why SagePay is ignoring the VendorEMail parameter even though, I am sending it.

Thanks in advance

Mathew

Comment: Hi Rik 
Thanks for replying. I am following the procedure specified in the document  http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/sage-pay-form
which is the Form integration method

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but it isn't working because Sage Pay will only send an email when using the Form protocol. You appear to be using Server, so will need to handle notifications to merchant and customer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

After interacting with SagePay support, I realized that I was using the Server Integration method instead of the Form integration method. Since I was being redirected to the SagePay site for entering credit card details, I assumed that I am using the Form integration method.

Thanks and regards

Mathew